# Javascript event running wrong function

Tags: javascript, loops, events, scope

I have a for loop which is supposed to assign functions based on user input (binding the function to a button). Instead, no matter which button is clicked (except the cancel button) the same function runs.

The function looks like this...

Per the requests below, here's a cleaner example :

**HTML**

```
<button id="myButton">
 Button 1
</button>
<button id="myButton2">
  Button 2
</button>
<button id="myButton3">
  Button 3
</button>
```

**JAVASCRIPT**

```
 var myFunctions = {
            myButton: function(o){ alert("Button 1 pressed! (" + o +")"); },
        myButton2: function(o){ alert("Button 2 pressed! (" + o +")"); },
        myButton3: function(o){ alert("Button 3 pressed! (" + o +")"); }
    }
    function runBinds(binds){
          for(bind in binds){
                var myButton = document.getElementById(bind),
                    myCall = function(){
                        binds[bind]("Appended info");
                };
            myButton.addEventListener('click',myCall,false);
        }
    }

    runBinds(myFunctions);
```

Jsfiddle

[With closures](https://jsfiddle.net/PhantomDude95/ug19xsmy/1/)

[Without closures](https://jsfiddle.net/PhantomDude95/ug19xsmy/2/)

As I mentioned before, I tried using closures and this did not resolve my issue, so it is not a duplicate.

Comment: There is a lot going on here, some of which is based on DOM selectors when you're not showing any HTML. Instead break the code down to a minimal example that reproduces the problem.

Comment: Please update your answer this is a mess. just show your html and eventlistener function

Comment: I have updated the question with simplified code.

Comment: @Ethan, what's happening is that the button is clicked, `myCall()` is called, and then `binds[bind]()` is executed. The `myCall` function is a closure around the `bind` variable. After the loop finishes, the value of `bind` is "myButton3". What you want to do is pass the value of `bind` instead like : https://jsfiddle.net/ug19xsmy/4/

Comment: Wow, that's exactly what I was looking for. Thank you! Want to post as an answer so I can mark it correct?

Comment: This seems to work: for(let bind in binds){....   (note the 'let')

Comment: Interesting... Unfortunately neither are actually working in my larger project... Guess I'll just have to figure it out. Between the let trick and  the answer @mowwwalker gave, should be good....